# Плохой стиль программирования

Tags: java, code-style

Является ли данный пример, плохим стилем написания кода? Лучше ли использовать другие имена переменных в конструкторе?

```
Class Myclass{
   String name;
   String lastName;
   Myclass(String name, String lastName){
       this.name = name;
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }
}
```

Comment: `class` с маленькой буквы пишется. В данном примере можно изменить название класса `Myclass`, модификатор доступа для коструктора и полей. Возможно добавление `final`, но это уже зависит от контекста

Comment: @Andrei_Ert если вопрос касается только инициализации полей в конструкторе, то использование одинаковых имён и this - абсолютно нормальная практика, большинство её придерживается.